# How to convert char to ascii value in kotlin language

Tags: android, kotlin

I am developing an android application with `kotlin` in which I need to convert an string character to its `ASCII` value,

```
fun tryDiCript(cypher: String) :String {
        var cypher = "fs2543i435u@$#g#@#sagb@!#12416@@@"
        var originalText = ""

        var regEx =Regex("[a-z]")
        for(char in  regEx.findAll(cypher))
        {                 
            originalText += (char.value.toInt()).toString()            
        }
       return originalText
}
```

[this tutorial website](https://www.programiz.com/kotlin-programming/examples/ascii-value-character) showed me to use `char.toInt()` but it gives runtime error saying

> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "u"

so how if anyone knows hot to convert char to ASCII value please help me.

Comment: You mean convert a character to its code?

Comment: @JulianSoto yes, mean  `a= 97` `b=98` like that

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`char.value` is a `String`. When you call `String.toInt()`, it is expecting a numeric string such as `"1", "-123"` to be parsed to `Int`. So, `"f".toInt()` will give you `NumberFormatException` since `"f"` isn't a numeric string.

If you are sure about `char.value` is a `String` containing exactly one character only. To get the ascii value of it, you can use:

```
char.value.first().code
```

Comment: finally your solution worked thanks , and I used `char.value[0].toInt()` does it make any difference with yours?

Comment: No, no difference

Comment: No. The only difference is the exception thrown if the string is empty. `first()` will give you `NoSuchElementException` while `get(Int)` will give you `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: Exception will never thrown in my case as it is in foreach loop , thanks :)

Answer (score 16):

### Since Kotlin 1.5

if your variable is of type char for example 'a' you can simply use `a.code`.

The old methods (e.g. `toByte()`) are deprecated now.

Answer (score 8):

You said **ascii**, not **unicode**. So it's easy.

This is an example that shows you how to convert a char (`'A'`) to it's ascii value.

```
fun main(vararg args: String) {
  println('A'.toByte().toInt())
}
```

The output is what we expected, 65.

Note this doesn't work with unicode.

### Edit 1

I guess this to work.

```
fun tryDiCript(cypher: String): String {
    var cypher = "fs2543i435u@$#g#@#sagb@!#12416@@@"
    var originalText = ""

    var regEx = Regex("[a-z]")
    for(char in regEx.findAll(cypher))
        originalText += char.value[0].toInt().toString()            
    return originalText
}
```

And I recommend you to use `StringBuilder`.

```
fun tryDiCript(cypher: String): String {
    var cypher = "fs2543i435u@$#g#@#sagb@!#12416@@@"
    val originalText = StringBuilder()

    var regEx = Regex("[a-z]")
    for(char in regEx.findAll(cypher))
        originalText.append(char.value[0].toInt())
    return originalText.toString()
}
```

Comment: The code with problem was missing before,? Now ,I have changed it , check it please, and let me know where i'm mistaking

Comment: `The code with problem was missing before,?` Sorry I didn't understand this sentence, have you missed something between the `,` and `?`?

Comment: simply check my edited question and please help me to figure it out it is not working with character when fetched with regEx matching

Answer (score 4):

I checked @ice1000's answer, I found the block below does not work.

```
fun main(vararg args: String) {
  println('A'.toByte().toInt())
}
```

As we can see in the Kotlin Documentation [String - Kotlin Programming Language](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-string/index.html),the `toByte()` function of `String` "Parses the string as a signed Byte number and returns the result." If the the content of the string is not a number, it will throw a `java.lang.NumberFormatException`.

But there is another function of `String` called `toByteArray()`,this function does no require the content of the string being numbers. My code is as following:

```
String tempString = "Hello"
val tempArray = tempString.toByteArray()
for (i in tempArray){
    println(i.toInt())
}
```

Attention that `toByteArray()` function's definition in kotlin's documentaion:

```
fun String.toByteArray(
    charset: Charset = Charsets.UTF_8
): ByteArray
```

The default charset is UTF-8, if you would like to use other charset, you can modify it with the parameter.

Comment: In the code example, `'A'` is not a `String`.